# How could I improve the runtime of this code?

Tags: python, pandas, runtime

I want to share some information betweeen two dataframes. My code works but takes a long time. Do you know how I could improve my runtime? I am trying to do the following:

I have a dataframe `df1` (it has 160 columns, but only the ones shown are important here):

```
         a_idx  b_idx  c_idx  d_idx  e_idx  f_idx Evt_ID
    0    0      1      3      4      2      6     346642
    1    1      2      3      4      5      5     917426
    2    0      1      3      4      2      2     123543
                        ...
```

And a dataframe `df2` ( ist has 10 columns, but only these are important here):

```
    Name    Evt_ID
0   Jet1    346642
1   Jet2    346642
2   Jet3    346642
3   Jet4    346642
4   Jet5    346642
5   Jet6    346642
6   Jet7    346642
7   Lepton  346642
8   Jet1    917426
9   Jet2    917426
      ...
```

Now I want a new column in `df2` called "y" with the category of each line.  The category can be found with help of `df1` and the categories are:
`category_list = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]` and can also be `"unknown"`. For example the first line in df1 has the values `category = [0,1,3,4,2,6]` which means that `df2` should look like this:

(explanation: **fifth** number in `category` is **2** --> Jet(**2**+1) = Jet3 has the **fifth** category in `category_list`: **"e"**)

```
    Name    Evt_ID    y
0   Jet1    346642    a
1   Jet2    346642    b
2   Jet3    346642    e
3   Jet4    346642    c
4   Jet5    346642    d
5   Jet6    346642    unknown
6   Jet7    346642    f
7   Lepton  346642    unknown
     ...
```

My way to achieve this is the following:

```
df["y"] = "unknown"
category_list = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]

for event_id in tqdm(df1.Evt_ID):
    category = df1.loc[df1.Evt_ID == event_id, ["a_idx","b_idx",
                                               "c_idx", "d_idx", 
                                               "e_idx", "f_idx"]].values.squeeze()
    
    i = 0
    for jet_index in category:
        df2.loc[(dfo.Evt_ID == event_id) & (dfo.Name == "Jet".join(str(jet_index+1))), "y"] = category_list[i] 
        i += 1
```

This code take 30 or 60 minutes to run, depending on the jupyter notebook it is running in. Why would the notebook itself affect the runtime? But more important: How can I improve the runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following snippet should run way faster thanks to its vectorized structure.

There are two tricks here. First one is to use `df.melt` which efficiently turns the columns `a`, `b`, ..., `e` into rows. Second one is to `join` the resulting DataFrame with `df2`. That way, all missing values become `NaN` and can be replaced with `unknown` with `df.fillna`.

```py
cols = ["a_idx", "b_idx", "c_idx", "d_idx", "e_idx", "f_idx"]
df = df1[cols + ["Evt_ID"]].rename(columns={c: c[0] for c in cols})

df = df.melt(id_vars="Evt_ID", var_name="y")
df["value"] = "Jet" + (df["value"] + 1).astype(str)

df = df2.join(df.set_index(["Evt_ID", "value"]), on=["Evt_ID", "Name"])
df = df.fillna("unknown")
```

In the end, `df` looks like:

```py
     Name  Evt_ID        y
0    Jet1  346642        a
1    Jet2  346642        b
2    Jet3  346642        e
3    Jet4  346642        c
4    Jet5  346642        d
5    Jet6  346642  unknown
6    Jet7  346642        f
7  Lepton  346642  unknown
8    Jet1  917426  unknown
9    Jet2  917426        a
```

This result was obtained with the following sample data:

```py
import pandas as pd


df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        [0, 1, 3, 4, 2, 6, 346642],
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 917426],
        [0, 1, 3, 4, 2, 2, 123543],
    ],
    columns=["a_idx", "b_idx", "c_idx", "d_idx", "e_idx", "f_idx", "Evt_ID"],
)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ["Jet1", 346642],
        ["Jet2", 346642],
        ["Jet3", 346642],
        ["Jet4", 346642],
        ["Jet5", 346642],
        ["Jet6", 346642],
        ["Jet7", 346642],
        ["Lepton", 346642],
        ["Jet1", 917426],
        ["Jet2", 917426],
    ],
    columns=["Name", "Evt_ID"],
)
```

Comment: Yes this reduced the runtime from 30 -60 min to less than a second. I didn't know about df.melt(), thats really useful. Thank you very much!

Comment: Yay! Glad it helped!